# Route in the modal does nt work angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with my route in modal, I can retrieve my first route ("/",menu.html) but when I press the buttons, the other routes do not appear.

This is my route:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){    
    $stateProvider
        .state("foo", {
            url: "/foo",
            template: '<h1>foo</h1>'
        })
        .state("menu", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: 'menu.html'
        })
        .state("bar", {
            url: "/bar",
            template: '<h1>bar</h1>'
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

This is my modal with the div view:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 ui-view-container">
            <div class="well" ui-view></div>        
        </div>
    </div>       
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And this is my `menu.html`:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Quick Start</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#/foo">Route 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/bar">Route 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a [simple plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u57y3lSk0ygEULPPkpen?p=preview) with a modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State provider has `ui-sref` to handle route which takes the state name to navigate.

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a ui-sref="foo">Route 1</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="bar">Route 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

When you open the modal, run it to a default state 'menu' through `$state.go('menu')`.
In order for this to work, inject $state in the controller as bellow:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', 
function ($uibModal, $log, $document, $state) {
 ......

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    $state.go('menu');
    ......
  }
});
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qbIhTt9cgMsOUQxLvVSD?p=preview) updated with comment query.

Comment: thanks sir :D but just one more things , when i re put on the modal i have the last menu selected and i want to come back in menu.html

Comment: Please see the update to my answer. Kindly note, i wont be answering any more queries on this as it solves your initial problem. Please close this thread and post new questions for other queries.